# Omit current and parent directories in Ivy find-file completion

Tags: spacemacs, find-file, ivy

I'm using Ivy in a fairly standard Spacemacs setup.

When I'm opening a file I'd like `.` and `..` to be omitted from the list of completion candidates. In particular, I'd like to be able to tab through directories with only one entry; right now if I spam <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the middle of a long Java path I get a Dired buffer for a directory I don't particularly care about.

E.g., if my current directory is `~/src` and I find a file in the following file hierarchy, I'd like <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> to open `java/com/example/foo/Bar.java`.

```
ls -R
.:
Makefile java

./java:
com

./java/com:
example

./java/com/example:
foo

./java/com/example/foo:
Bar.java
Quux.java
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `ivy-extra-directories` to `nil`? See [`(ivy) File Name Completion`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#file-name-completion).

Comment: @Basil This worked -- please add it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I'm opening a file I'd like `.` and `..` to be omitted from the list of completion candidates.

This is what the user option `ivy-extra-directories` is for:

```
ivy-extra-directories is a variable defined in ‘ivy.el’.
Its value is ("../" "./")

Documentation:
Add this to the front of the list when completing file names.
Only "./" and "../" apply here.  They appear in reverse order.
```

In your case, you just need to clear the list:

```el
(setq ivy-extra-directories ())
```

Quoth [`(ivy) File Name Completion`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#file-name-completion):

```
-- User Option: ivy-extra-directories
    Decide if you want to see ‘../’ and ‘./’ during file name
    completion.

    Reason to remove: ‘../’ is the same as ‘DEL’.

    Reason not to remove: navigate anywhere with only ‘C-n’, ‘C-p’ and
    ‘C-j’.

    Likewise, ‘./’ can be removed.
```